# SPREADSHEET. Script to adjust sum function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet for work which contains roughly about 90 sheets.

1. On the first sheet is a table of our workers hours.
2. On the second
   sheet is a sum function which displays the result on the first
   sheet(it just sums up the hours).

   I need to add the sum function for only couple of cells in the rest of the 90 sheets. This is the function, all the cells are always the same only on different sheets.

   ```
   =SUMA(Sheet2'!B11;'Sheet2'!G11;'Sheet2'!L11;'Sheet2'!Q11;'Sheet2'!V11;'Sheet2'!AA11;'Sheet2'!AF11)
   ```

Is there a way for me to by "dragging" the little + when I choose the table to keep the cells the same but change the sheet to the next one? Doing it manually would take forever.

Comment: there are ways to do this if your sheets are numbered... is that your case?

Comment: they are not, but if they were?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Next Sheet Same Range**

```
function nextSheetSameRange() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ash=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var arg=ash.getActiveRange();
  var argA1=arg.getA1Notation();
  var shts=ss.getSheets();
  for(var i=0;i<shts.length;i++) {
    if(ash.getName()==shts[i].getName()) {
      var currentIdx=i;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(currentIdx<shts.length-1) {
    nextSh=shts[currentIdx+1];
  }else{
    nextSh=shts[0];
  }
  var nsh=ss.setActiveSheet(nextSh);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var nrg=nsh.getRange(argA1);
  nsh.setActiveRange(nrg);
}

function makeSidebar() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var html='<input type="button" value="next" onClick="google.script.run.nextSheetSameRange()" />';
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(userInterface);
}
```

**Instructions**

1. > Run makeSidebar. It will create a sidebar with a button labeled next. You only have to do this once.  I like to use the side bar since it just takes one click and I don't have to mess around with drop down menu's.
2. > Press the button and it will move one sheet to the right and select the same range as your current active range.  When it gets to the end it will wrap around to the beginning again with the same range selected.

If you already have a sidebar then add this html to the createHtmlOutput string `'<input type="button" value="next" onClick="google.script.run.nextSheetSameRange()" />'`

Comment: Ok I have the button and the script works but how should I put it into the sum function? On the first sheet I have list of names lets say Client1, Client2, Client3 and then the second third and fourth sheets are called Client1, Client2, Client3 and the client sheets have number of hours always in the same cells so I need sum function from client1 to be shown on the first sheet and I was wondering if I can "drag" the existing table from the first sheet and the table will use the same cells but from the sheets next to the previous one.

Comment: Sorry I am already working on it. Old fashioned way. But thanks for your help.